# What happened to the Dancer of the Boreal Valley after I defeated Aldrich, the devourer of souls?

Tags: ps4, dark-souls-3

I defeated Aldrich, lord of souls, and after placing the basin of vows on the beheaded soldier, was immediately engaged to battle The Dancer of the Boreal Valley, who defeated me quickly.

The thing is: when I went back to the room in Lothric castle to fight her again, the room had changed and she was gone. There was now a lift on either side of the front of the room and the lift led to a small room where I received the sunlight princess ring.

I checked online for information but could find nothing. I can't find her to fight again and the ladder that would lead to the king's garden (the next and last level) is not there.

Please help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: Dancer of the boreal *forest*? http://i.imgur.com/B0OM5k8.png (yes I really did just make this)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The room you are talking about (with two elevators leading to the Sun Princess Ring) is *not* Lothric Castle -- it is Aldritch's boss room in Anor Londo. To find the Dancer of the Boreal Valley again, travel to the bonfire for Vordt, exit the boss room, then run straight until you see the door to Lothric Castle, which should now appear as a fog door. This fog door is the entrance to the Dancer fight.

Comment: thank you for the answer pushasha. (and yes, I should have asked for the Dancer of the Boreal "Valley", not forest. But you knew that. thx

Comment: @Rhaunn If my answer helped, feel free to select it by clicking the checkmark next to it, which will mark it as the "selected answer". Thanks!

Comment: done and done. thx again. it was awesome help in a confusing moment...